# "PrintWriter" is not recognized by eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I have Eclipse(Kepler) IDE and when I write the below code.

```
PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
```

It displays an error message saying that PrintWriter cannot be resolved to type. The import statements that I have used are as follows,

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
```

Do I have to import some additional statements to get my PrintWriter to work? If yes then which are they?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why do you have `javax.servlet.http.*` *and* specific classes in javax.servlet.http?

Comment: @andrewcooke actually they are automatically imported by Eclipse when I define a Servlet

Comment: that doesn't make it right.

Comment: @andrewcooke yeah I know that dude I was just saying the reason why they were there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Er, yes, you need to import `java.io.PrintWriter`.  Or `java.io.*`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to import `java.io.PrintWriter`.

Eclipse provides a useful shortcut to **Organize Imports**, `Ctrl + Shift + O`. By default this imports each class explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is the following

```
   import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
```

Comment: Bad advice!  Over use of wildcard imports makes your code fragile when you attempt to recompile against new releases of Java / new class libraries.